# Вывод ошибок на экран в С++

Tags: c++

можно ли в С++ вывести на экран ошибки в программе? если да, то можете привести маленький пример кода? Если будет с объяснениями, то вдвойне буду благодарен.

Comment: Вам, наверное, нужно почитать про обработку ошибок в C++.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *f = fopen("noname", "rb");

    if (f == NULL)
        perror("[Error] ");
    else
        fclose(f);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Есть такая штука, как GCC. Но большинство современных компиляторов используют её на автомате, то есть ошибки выводятся в определенные лог-лист(как в Dev-CPP). Она выявляет логические ошибки в программном коде, поддерживает великое множество всяких спецификаторов(например, если надо искать только ошибки, связанные с неправильным выделением памяти и т.д). Для C++ я бы рекомендовал использовать следующие набор спецификаторов:

> -Wctor-dtor-privacy -Weffc++ -Wold-style-cast -Woverloader-virtual

Применять спецификаторы необходимо именно на этапе компиляции.

Пояснения к некоторым спецификаторам:

> // -Weffc++  --- предупреждает о ряде нарушений из книг Скотта Мейерса "Effective C++".
> Например, к ним относятся виртуфльные деструкторы для базовых классов, а также 
> опредедения копирующих конструкторов для классов с членами-указателями

**Дополнение:**

Для того, чтобы вывести ошибку в программный код, спользуйте для этого комбинацию

> try->throw->catch

Где "try" - попытка выполнить какой-л. код, "throw" - генерация исключительной ситуации, если возникла ошибка в блоке "try". И "catch" - обработка сгенерированной ситуации(можно вывести ошибку, например)

Comment: Другие современные компиляторы тоже сообщения об ошибках выводят. Хотелось бы понять, что же хочет @navi1893

Comment: @Asen а что скажете на счет cerr? Его можно в этих целях использовать?

@Alexiz я хочу, чтобы ошибки находящиеся в программе выводились как результат программы, т.е в командной строке, а не в компиляторе.

Comment: @navi1893, тут действовать надо на своё усмотрение. Ведь можно применить сразу все спецификаторы GCC, которых порядка 50. Но этого же никто не делает. Если компилятор выдает ошибку в приведении типа данных, то можно подключить и "cerr", но я перечислил самые основные и эффективные.

Comment: да, понятно. А вот нельзя чтобы ошибки находящиеся в программе выводились как результат программы? т.е чтобы я ничего потом не вводил, а ошибки выводились как вот cout. Возможно такое?

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: А кто такой cerr? Шутка. Ошибки выводятся на stderr (хэндл 2), а не stdout (хендл 1). "Ошибки в программе выводились как результат программы"? видимо речь о том, что эта информация в какой-то IDE помещается в разные окна. Если так, то это уже преобразования вывода компилятора, осуществляемые этой IDE. Внутри оно, скорее всего так и выводит: ошибки на stderr, что-нибудь (надо доки читать) на stdout. Попробуйте запустить компилятор (кстати, какой?) из командной строки

Comment: @Asen спасибо большое, последний вопрос задам. Куда вставить этот код?

Comment: В блок "try" вставляете код, в котором может произойти ошибка, затем генерируете её, используя "throw" и затем в блоке "catch" выводите. В сети по этой конструкции очень много инфы. Да, кстати, если вас устраивает мой ответ, то примите его пожалуйста =)

Comment: недостаточно репутации ))

Comment: ну ладно тогда...